# Flutter/Flutter.h file missing from project issue in ios Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

My project is giving me the error of Flutter.h file missing. I have tried almost everything I could find on stackOverflow and other few forums but the issue still persists this happened just after i cleaned my build folder.

I have tried cleaning build folder again, flutter clean, pod install, pod deintegrate and re install, pod update and many more things.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec and then hit the below command

```
$ rm ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
$ flutter clean
```